# C# how to capture error and debugging prepared statements?

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

Hi all below is my snippet of C# codes with multiple insert statement. I put them into a transaction bracket and I using prepared statement. My challenge for instance I know I got issue in now cmdText3 but there is no any error message generated. How in this scenario where should I be adding extra try and catch to help me debug and alert me on the error? Can in prepared statement I see what is the exact query being executed with the data?

myCon getMyCon1 = new myCon();
        MySqlConnection con = getMyCon1.GetConnection();

```
    using (MySqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            long rID = 0;
            String cmdText1 = "INSERT INTO record1(fiscalPeriod,financialYear) VALUES(@fiscalPeriod,@financialYear)";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText1, con, trans))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fiscalPeriod", fiscalPeriod.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@financialYear", financialYear.SelectedValue);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                rID = cmd.LastInsertedId;
            }

            foreach (object line in linesC)
            {
                if (line.GetType() == typeof(TypeC))
                {
                    TypeC typesC = (TypeC)line;                           
                    String companyName = typesC.comName;                            
                    String periodStart = typesC.periodStart;
                    String periodEnd = typesC.periodEnd;                          

                    String cmdText2 = "INSERT INTO record2(rID,companyName,,periodStart,periodEnd,) VALUES(@rID,@companyName,@periodStart,@periodEnd)";
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText2, con, trans))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rID", rID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyName", companyName);                                
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@periodStart", periodStart);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@periodEnd", periodEnd);                               
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (object line in linesP)
            {
                if (line.GetType() == typeof(TypeP))
                {
                    TypeP typesP = (TypeP)line;
                    String supplierName = typesP.supName;                          
                    String invoiceDate = typesP.invoiceDate;
                    String invoiceNo = typesP.invoiceNo;

                    String cmdText3 = "INSERT INTO record2(rID,supplierName,invoiceDate,invoiceNo) VALUES(@rID,@supplierName,@invoiceDate,@invoiceNo,)";
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText3, con, trans))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rID", rID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierName", supplierName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceDate", invoiceDate);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceNo", invoiceNo);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    }
                }

            }
            trans.Commit();                    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
        }
    }
    con.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see the exact query using the Sql Profiler app.  This will allow you to see both the queries generated and the responses from Sql Server.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: The problem is that my database is mysql not sqlserver? Where else can I add try and catch to let me know which specific insert is having issue?

Comment: Why are you using Sql specific classes for a non-sql server database?  You need to use the correct ADO.Net library for your DB Server.

Comment: Ya I am using using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;. I dont get you when you said sql specific classes?

Comment: LOL, it didn't register to me that you were using MySql from the name of the classes.  I apologize for that.  Having said that, I believe there are profiling tools available for MySql as well.  Here's one (Google is your friend): http://www.profilesql.com/

Comment: Ok basically what this tool will do is save the queries is it? My next challenge is based on my codes can I put some extra try and catch to highlight which query is having issue?

Comment: The profiler should show you the output for each query.  Once you find the one that is failing it's trivial to fix it in your code.

Comment: A bigger question is why not use EntityFramework?  It does all of this for you.

Comment: I am sorry I will need time how to install and execute the profiler. For actual production must I still need the profiler to help me?

Comment: I think I must learn the framework and that will again take more time for me to develop. I dont mind writing my own codes just I guess need some improvements?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
String cmdText3 = "INSERT INTO record2(rID,supplierName,invoiceDate,invoiceNo) VALUES(@gafID,@supplierName,@invoiceDate,@invoiceNo,)";
```

Does not correspond with the first parameter you're specifying here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rID", rID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplierName", supplierName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceDate", invoiceDate);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceNo", invoiceNo);
```

---

Replace:

```
VALUES(@gafID,@supplierName,@invoiceDate,@invoiceNo,)
```

With:

```
VALUES(@rID,@supplierName,@invoiceDate,@invoiceNo)
```

---

Alternatively you can re-name:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rID", rID);
```

To:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gafID", rID);
```

Comment: Sorry I have rectify that in my question. I mistakenly copied. But back to my actual problem what do you suggest to pin point which query is having issue or problematic?